# Converting sha256 hash into decimal equivalent string

Tags: java, android, hash, sha

I am developing a secure communication between android and arduino with sha256.
Doing so i got successfully the HEX decimal equivalent string but my goal is to get Decimal equivalent string.i searched out a lot but did not get success.
Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance
this is my android code for hashing  "12345678901234567890123456789077"

```
 String hashfirst="12345678901234567890123456789077";
           MessageDigest digest = null;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println(bytesToHex(hash));
    }
    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xFF) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
```

The Resultant Hash string is(through android)

```
21de5812f71df17b25a5124129ba1ccf5ba67121c548c9f8127f68d9d11293f8
```

Comment: I would use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the build in hex conversion of `BigInteger`:

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger(bytesToHex(hash),16));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Integer.toString((b & 0xFF) + 0x100, 16).substring(1)
```

Try to use:

```
String.format("%03d", (b & 0xFF) + 0x100);
```

Comment: This will give you fixed-length decimal number for your hash.